# Correct model for comparing frequencies of comorbidities, large numbers

Tags: chi-squared-test, frequency, relative-risk, risk-difference

Here is what my group wants to do:

Query a database for cases of several disorders, including Disorder A and Disorder B.
Of those cases, specifically query for cases of Disorder A comorbid with each of the other disorders, including Disorder B.
Compare frequencies of A+B comorbidity vs. A + each other comorbidities, adjusting for the population frequency of B and the other disorders.

Chi square won't work because of the large sample size. When the sample gets large enough, all chi square tests are "significant". This is a risk-difference or relative risk question, right?

What would be an appropriate test?

Comment: Unclear exactly what you are asking. Anyway all tests are significant with large sample size.

Comment: Given a database of patients diagnosed with a specific disease, how would one compare frequencies of different comorbid conditions, taking into account the baseline population frequency of each comorbidity?

It can't be expressed more basic than that.